# How can I open Android Studio from any directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu

This instruction was listed:

[OPTIONAL] Add "{installation home}/bin" to your PATH environment variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory.

So I did these following steps:

First opened .profile

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

Edited this line:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/home/username/android-studio/bin/"
fi
```

After that I entered this in the home directory:

```
studio.sh    //didn't work
```

Again,

```
./studio.sh  //still not working
```

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Is your username `username`, or did you obfuscate this for stackoverflow? Does `/home/username/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` work?

Comment: Try `export PATH=/home/<uername>/path/to/android-studio/bin:$PATH`

Comment: @Michiel Obfuscating :D

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti


`# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
   # PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/home/scarface/android-studio/bin/"
   export PATH="$HOME:/home/scarface/android-studio/bin:$PATH"
fi`

I'm new. 
Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem that people face. **Just editing your `.bashrc` or `.profile` will not work.** You either have to reboot, or re-source your `.bashrc` or `.profile` file. (In your case, `.profile` file). To do that, run this command :-

```
source ~/.profile
```

So edit your `.profile` file like you did on your question, then do this. After that, you should be able to launch anywhere by `studio.sh`

Comment: How about `alias android-studio='/home/username/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`?